# Error Message upon trying to download application Iriun Webcam

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg, webcam

I'm having trouble trying to install the app Iriun Webcam for Ubuntu (PopOs!20.04).

In the terminal I receive the following:

### ***Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Setting up v4l2loopback-dkms (0.12.3-1) ...
Removing old v4l2loopback-0.12.3 DKMS files...

### Deleting module version: 0.12.3
completely from the DKMS tree.

Done.
Loading new v4l2loopback-0.12.3 DKMS files...
Building for 5.8.0-7625-generic
Building initial module for 5.8.0-7625-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-5.8.0-7625-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.8.0-7625-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/v4l2loopback/0.12.3/build/make.log for more information.
dpkg: error processing package v4l2loopback-dkms (--configure):
installed v4l2loopback-dkms package post-installation script subprocess returne
d error exit status 10
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of iriunwebcam:
iriunwebcam depends on v4l2loopback-dkms; however:
Package v4l2loopback-dkms is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing package iriunwebcam (--configure):
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup erro
r from a previous failure.
Errors were encountered while processing:
v4l2loopback-dkms
iriunwebcam
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)***

It will not allow me to install said app.

I'd appreciate the help thanks in advance.

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux*)

Comment: @RallyFlow Bro thanks for posting this question, as I just ran into this problem myself.  Check out this Reddit thread for one solution: https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/jkpe5b/need_help_iriun_webcam_app_failing_to_install/